# Validation only works for first row and does not work for other rows! I feel it's because of the return true/false but I need that in my validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, validation

`HTML PHP`

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?php echo $i;?>" name="r2<?php echo $i+1;?>" onblur="mvalidate2()" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc;width: 46px;">
        <label id="errora<?php echo $i;?>" style="font-size:13px; color:#cc0000;margin-left: 5px;"><div style = "font-size:13px; color:#cc0000;"></div></label></td>
```

//I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at mvalidate2

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
function mvalidate2(){
 var count = <?php echo $count2;?>;
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var sr = document.getElementById(i).value;
    var temp  = 'errora';
    var t = temp.concat(i);

    if(sr<5){
     document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=" ";
     return true;
     }
    else{
     document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=" Enter valid Rating out of 4 ";
     return false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour]  and read [ask]!

Comment: Yes, of course it is because you are using return inside the loop - that makes it leave your whole function during the first loop iteration already. You need to find a way to collect/accumulate all the validation results, and only return true or false once _after_ your loop. (A boolean flag is a simple way to do that.)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null it says this now

Comment: Please format your codes properly, when you make edits to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start ID by number in JavaScript

```js
    var sr = document.getElementById("inp"+i).value;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inp<?php echo $i;?>" name="r2<?php echo $i+1;?>" onblur="mvalidate2()" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc;width: 46px;">
```

```js
function mvalidate2(){
 var count = <?php echo $count2;?>;
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var temp  = 'errora';
    var t = temp.concat(i);

    if(sr<5){
     document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=" ";
     return true;
     }
    else{
     document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=" Enter valid Rating out of 4 ";
     return false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks But this only works for the 1st row, the validation does not work for the rest.